# How do I get the margin to extend all the way to the left-hand side?

Tags: asp.net

I started a new project as an ASP.NET Web Application and have been going from there modifying it to my needs, but I cannot figure out how to get rid of the margin on the left so that my page can expand to fill the display. You can see the space to the left of the table in the image linked below. No matter what I put in the white area it cannot expand any further left, even if it has to expand enough to the right to put a horizontal scrollbar on the screen. I'd like to avoid a horizontal scrollbar. What should I change to get rid of this margin?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrkWN.jpg

Answer (score 1):

From the image it's not possible to inspect the code but I suggest to make sure your style sheets have the right width.

> "keep calm and start coding" [(etabetaweb)](https://etabetaweb.com)